# Accordion doesn't expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created an accordion with the help of a tutorial and some demo files and even though the demo file works, when I transferred it over to my HTML file, it doesn't expand upon clicking. The weird thing is that when I copy pasted it to a jsfiddle, it works. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Heres my HTML,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>What is Diabetes?</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:300,400|Roboto:100,200,300,400,800,900|Source+Sans+Pro:300,400|Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/accordion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--Fonts-->

</head>

<body>

<div id="container"> <!-- Container for Everything -->


<div class="divider1"></div>

<div class="sectionbanner">
<h2>WHAT IS DIABETES?</h2>
</div>

<div class="divider1"></div>

<div id="whatisdiabetes">
<p>Diabetes or diabetes mellitus is a chronic disease where the body does not make or does not use insulin properly, resulting in having too much sugar (glucose) in the blood. Sugar comes from the food we eat. The body needs sugar to make energy. The amount of sugar in the blood of a normal person is closely controlled by a substance called insulin. Insulin is made by the pancreas, a gland found below the stomach. People with diabetes either do not produce enough insulin or the insulin produced does not work well. As a result, sugar builds up in the blood.<br><br>

Over time, high sugar levels can give rise to problems like infections, blindness, kidney disorders, stroke, heart disease, and foot and leg disorders.</p>
</div>

<div id="faq">

<div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-section">
                <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">Accordion Section #1</a>
                <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
                    <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Duis congue ullamcorper vehicula. Proin nunc lacus, semper sit amet elit sit amet, aliquet pulvinar erat. Nunc pretium quis sapien eu rhoncus. Suspendisse ornare gravida mi, et placerat tellus tempor vitae.</p>
                </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-->

            <div class="accordion-section">
                <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">Accordion Section #2</a>
                <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
                    <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Duis congue ullamcorper vehicula. Proin nunc lacus, semper sit amet elit sit amet, aliquet pulvinar erat. Nunc pretium quis sapien eu rhoncus. Suspendisse ornare gravida mi, et placerat tellus tempor vitae.</p>
                </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-->

            <div class="accordion-section">
                <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-3">Accordion Section #3</a>
                <div id="accordion-3" class="accordion-section-content">
                    <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Duis congue ullamcorper vehicula. Proin nunc lacus, semper sit amet elit sit amet, aliquet pulvinar erat. Nunc pretium quis sapien eu rhoncus. Suspendisse ornare gravida mi, et placerat tellus tempor vitae.</p>
                </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-->
</div><!--end .accordion-->

</div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As for my JS and CSS, it is exactly how I put it in the jsfiddle. I'm honestly stumped and confused as to why it works in jsfiddle but not when I put it in my HTML using Dreamweaver.

Comment: "the weird thing is that when I copy pasted it to a jsfiddle, it works." This leads me to believe it's a library import issue with Jquery (or the accordion.js). Do you have a link to the fiddle? They are a little more human-friendly than SO pasted code.

Comment: try switching to an older jquery version

Comment: and first put your jquery above your custom js

Comment: Could we see your `accordion.js` file? does it require jQuery? If so, place it after.

Comment: You can often use the browsers F12 tools to check the Console, and see if there are any errors when trying to run your site.  If you are missing some jQuery links or if there is an error, it will tell you.

Comment: It worked now, I switched to a 2.x version of jquery and moved it above the js file. Thanks everyone!